# Pass a variable with Union[None,int] type to a function accepting int

Tags: python

```
from typing import Union

def a() -> Union[None, int]:
    pass

def b(i : int):
    pass

b(a())
```

VS Code shows an error as

```
Argument of type "int | None" cannot be assigned to parameter "i" of type "int" in function "b"
   Type "int | None" cannot be assigned to type "int"
     Type "None" cannot be assigned to type "int"
```

As the *a()* returns a (None or int) object, I can not pass the result to the b function. How can I overcome this? In some cases I know *a()* will return an integer and I want to call *b* on the result in that case but I can't.

Comment: parameter `i` has a narrower type `int` than what is being passed `int|None`, so there is a type incompatibility. Why not check the return value of `a()` before calling `b`? 
`result = a(); if result is not None: b(a())`

Comment: This is what's _supposed_ to happen, that's why you provide the type metadata. Handle the case it does return None, or use e.g. cast to assure the type checker it won't.

Comment: Type hints are just that, **hints**. They are not enforced at runtime. Your code will run just fine. You can ignore it with #type: ignore comment at that line, you can make a cast to pure int type, or you can do what @cs95 suggests and make sure you are not passing `None` to `b()`.

Answer (score 0):

You could check the type of the variable "i" in function "b" and handle the case where "i" is None by returning an error code, for example:

```
def b(i : Union[int,None]):
  if i is not None:
    # your code..
  else:
    return -1  #code error
```